# Logging in with username and password

Tags: python

So I'm new at coding and this is my first project, can someone review it and tell me where I can improve the code?

```
username = input("Please insert your username ") # enter username

password = input("Please insert your password ") #Enter password

tries = 0 #The number of tries the user gets

print("Please re-login")

while tries < 3 :

  input_username = input("Please re-input your username: ")

  input_password = input("Please re-input your password: ")

  if input_username == username and input_password == password :
    print("You have logged in !") 
    break

  if input_username != username or input_password != password :

    if input_password != password :
      print("Wrong password, please re-enter your password")

    elif input_username != username :
      print("Wrong username, please re-enter your username")

    else :
      print("Please enter your username and password")

 tries += 1

if not tries < 3 :
  print("Out of tries, please try again later")
```

This is my first project, and I'm very new at this, so I'm very grateful for your reviews

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really for code review, but for solving (technical) programming problems - your question would be more at home at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: However, there's some things to get out of the way immediately: keep an eye on the depth of your idents - those are meaningful in Python. The standard depth for a Python indent is 4, you would do well to follow that standard. People will likely point out that there's little point in getting a user to confirm a username and password they just entered this way. Your comments should state what a variable is really for - tries seems to be the number of tries so far (almost), not the number of tries a user gets (that's 3).

Comment: Everything looks good. Keep practicing and improving! What to do next? Anything!

Comment: Okay thanks for the review, i'll check out the site later

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine with this program. But You can make it more better, faster and readable.

Even if my code looks big, You should be able to understand what is going on.

Here is the Code:

```
def login(username, password):
    """
    Attempts to Verify Account.
    parameters:
        - username: get stored Username entered in Create Account.
        - password: get stored Password entered in Create Account.
    """
    print("\n--Please Login to Your Account!--\n")
    _username = input("Username: ") # Asks user to enter username to verify.
    _password = input("Password: ") # Asks user to enter password to verify.

    if username == _username and password == _password: # Checks if username and password matches.
        return True

    return False # if not verifed, returns False by default.

def main():
    """
    Main function for program, Handles 'Create Account' and 'Login'.
    """
    print("--Create Account--\n")
    username = input("Your Name: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    for i in range(5): # Run 'login' 5 times using 'for' Loop to allow total 5 attempts.
        if login(username, password): # If successfull, the 'main' function returns this and breaks the Loop.
            return print("Logged In Successfully!")
        else:
            print("Woops, Wrong Username or Password!")
        
    # If failed to login/run out of Attempts.
    return print("\nSorry, We Can't Verify it's you!\n")

# Calling the main function. 
main()
```

Don't get stressed by just looking it! To understand this code, all you need to know is basic python in details (In this case, Conditions and Functions).

Comment: This really is better, thanks a lot for your review 